# Self-reference as an argument

Tags: c#, class, reference

I have two classes, `Game1` and `Scene`. The `Game1` is calling the `Tick()` function of the active scene.

The function looks like this:

```
abstract public List<IRenderable> Tick(ref KeyboardState ks, ref MouseState ms, ref Game1 game);
```

How could I pass the `Game1` itself as a reference ? Using `this` does not work, because it's in read only.

Comment: Is it correct that the operation is Game1.Tick()?

Comment: The method is abstract? is that implemented?

Comment: This is by default reference

Comment: This is implemented of course.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that none of those three parameters actually needs a `ref`

Comment: @PearlSek pass your object to method using its name but before its name you should use `ref`. Consider that the object have to have value before passing to method.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a separate variable:

```
var t = this;
var result = scene.Tick(ref ks, ref ms, ref t);
```

although you won't be able to assign `this` to `t` after the method returns. It's not clear why the parameters to `Tick` are declared as `ref` however.

Comment: KeyboardStates and MouseStates are pretty heavy elements.

Comment: @PearlSek - Are they structs? If they are larger than ~16 bytes you should make them classes. If they are classes then you only need to pass them by `ref` if you are assigning to them in the method.

Comment: Maybe the Keyboard and Mouse elements, which are classes from XNA, don't need `ref` ; but I need to give a reference to the Game1 so the Scene can act for it.

Comment: @PearlSek - You don't need to pass by `ref` unless you are assigning to `game` within `Tick`. If you do need to pass by `ref` what do you do with the updated variable in the caller?